# How to put divs for text field and button in one line for mailchimp signup form that is in a table?

Tags: mailchimp

I've been trying to amend the code provided by Mailchimp which is included on a site I'm developing for the mailing list form.

Basically the code is included within a table and the Mailchimp code is in one cell of the table. The content is title, box to enter email address and "Submit" button. I would like to amend the code so that the contents of the cell are all on one line rather than under each other as is the current case.

The code and CSS can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/surfersteve1970/x9QLP/

Hopefully I've just done something stupid, as is often the case, but after hitting my head on my desk for the last hour I thought it best to try and ask for some help rather than cause further brain damage.

Thanks in anticipation of any help.

Steve

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/iphipps/CLFBj/1/

Both the email and button inputs were being displayed as block and not floated or displayed inline.  The code below worked for me.

```
#mc_embed_signup input.email{
display:inline-block;
}

#mc_embed_signup input.button {
display:inline-block;
}
```

Note:  in the attached jsfiddle, I changed the display on both selectors, then added the code below after a comment. For some reason jsfiddle doesn't seem to like css cascaded overrides.